# Convert XML without any attributes/metadata into a .NET object

Tags: c#, xml-deserialization

I have an object, and I convert it to XML using a modified DataContractSerializer.

I strip out all the metadata/namespaces etc. so the result is just:

`<myObject>
  <someProperty>5</someProperty>
    <mySubObjects>
      <mySubObject>...</mySubObject>
      <mySubObject>...</mySubObject>
 ...
</myObject>`

etc.

I wonder if it is possible to put this back into objects.

I was able to partially do it by using JSON.NET to convert it to JSon which works, but there is a problem with deserializing the JSon and Lists that I couldn't understand, despite reading several explanations about it on SO.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonText);
```

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type '...' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])
>   to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to
>   a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it
>   is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a
>   collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a
>   JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to
>   force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

There should be a more direct solution, there will never be an issue of trying to do an invalid cast as the source data is coming from the object too, some kind of mapping library or something should be able to take care of this. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm unclear what you are trying to do.  What do you mean by "put this back into objects?"  You said you tried something using JSON but it "whines about Lists an IEnumerables" which doesn't tell us much about what you tried to do.

Comment: Ignore the JSON part, I want to convert the XML into an object. Since there's no metadata I don't think XmlSerializer will work (when I try, I get an error 'invalid xml', but I can put the XML into an `XmlDocument` so it must be valid). I think I just need something to iterate through and map each entry to an object, but it has to be clever enough to deal with lists. I've clarified my question a bit (very stressed today!)

Comment: That structure looks like you should be able to use XMLSerilizer just fine.  It can handle arrays and lists and things.  You just have to create classes that match the structure you have there.  There are attributes you put on the classes that tell it the names of the tags.  Using your example as a guide, you would need a class named myObject, with an integer property called someProperty.  Then it would need an array or List<mySubObject> named mySubObjects.

Comment: Yep, that's what I have - since the source XML comes from the object being deserialized, is stripped of any metadata etc. and then is used to recreate the object. I just get the error `There is an error in XML document (1, 133). {"Input string was not in a correct format."}` without any explanation of how it's not the correct format. I wonder if it's doing an invalid cast? Since it doesn't have any info about the data types.

Comment: So you want to recreate the object even though you stripped it of metadata?  I'm not sure what that means but it doesn't sound possible.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Per the comments, here is how you would do it without having to convert to JSON

```
string xml = "<myObject>\n" +
             "  <someProperty>5</someProperty>\n" +
             "  <mySubObjects>\n" +
             "      <mySubObject>test</mySubObject>\n" +
             "      <mySubObject>test</mySubObject>\n" +
             "  </mySubObjects>\n" +
             "</myObject>\n";

using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(myObject));
    var obj = serializer.Deserialize(reader);

}
```

Supporting class:

```
[Serializable()]
public class myObject
{
    [XmlElement("someProperty")]
    public string someProperty { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("mySubObjects")]
    [XmlArrayItem("mySubObject", typeof(string))]
    public List<string> mySubObjects { get; set; }
}
```

********Previous response using JSON:**********

This code should do it for you:

```
string xml = "<myObject>\n" +
             "  <someProperty>5</someProperty>\n" +
             "  <mySubObjects>\n" +
             "      <mySubObject>test</mySubObject>\n" +
             "      <mySubObject>test</mySubObject>\n" +
             "  </mySubObjects>\n" +
             "</myObject>\n";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonText);
```

Here are the supporting classes:

```
public class MySubObjects
{
    public List<string> mySubObject { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public string someProperty { get; set; }
    public MySubObjects mySubObjects { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public MyObject myObject { get; set; }
}
```

The problem you were having is that it was trying to cast mySubObjects to an class instead of a List. This is because it sees each mySubObject as an object itself. By creating a class and exposing a List as a property, JSON.Net can then add each mySubObject to the exposed list. What it meant by changing it to a JSON array, is to take out the mySubObjects node completely, and just use multiple . JSON.Net would then see it as an array and convert it directly to a List instead of needing it to be encapsulated in a separate class. I hope I explained that correctly.

Comment: I see, that does make sense. I can't change the format though. Is there maybe some metadata attributes I can use to tell it that it's a `List<T>` without writing some complex custom deserializer class? If not, might just have to abandon this and maybe just store the xml without stripping all the metadata.

Comment: Please see my edit above. I think this will work for you. It skips having to use JSON and converts it using XmlSerializer. This way, you only need one class.